# How to resolve typing issues (undefined Document) in node_modules folder when adding lib ES2017?

Tags: typescript, node-modules, tsconfig

In a legecy typescript project running tsc@2.5.2, I wanted to access methods from ES2017, e.g. the `array.includes` method.

Therefore, I edited my `tsconfig.json` from this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "pretty": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "node_modules/@types",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "cli.ts"
  ]
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "pretty": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "node_modules/@types",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "cli.ts"
  ]
}
```

Basically, only the `lib` part changed, yet now I get a lot of type errors within my `node_modules` folder that Document is undefined, e.g.:

```
157     before(content: Document[], ...contents: any[]): Cheerio;
                        ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/cheerio/index.d.ts(157,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.


161     insertBefore(content: Document): Cheerio;
                              ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/cheerio/index.d.ts(161,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.


239     parseHTML(data: string, context?: Document, keepScripts?: boolean): Document[];
                                          ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/cheerio/index.d.ts(239,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.


239     parseHTML(data: string, context?: Document, keepScripts?: boolean): Document[];
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You dependencies are depending on the DOM library, so you have to add it to your project:

```
"lib": [
      "es6",
      "es2017",
      "DOM"
],
```

---

Reason: When you omit the library option in your [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) (search for `--lib`), the default libaries will be injected into your project.

The default libs are:

- For ES6 target:

  - DOM
  - ES6
  - DOM.Iterable
  - ScriptHost
- For ES5 target:

  - DOM
  - ES5
  - ScriptHost

Once you start defining the libraries, you have to be more explicit as only those defined will be injected.